# How can one assert in Django that a model field has already been populated from the DB?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django, is there an easy way to test that a model field on an object has already been queried from the database (e.g. an object coming from a foreign-key relationship)?

I would like to make an assertion like this in one of my tests to ensure that accessing a particular attribute on one of my objects won't trigger an additional database query.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, it sounds like you're trying to test Django functionality here rather than your own app's. This isn't the sort of thing you test for in your own unit tests.

Comment: I see where you're coming from. But no, I'm not testing Django functionality (e.g. `select_related()`). You could view this as a test to check that I'm taking advantage of such functionality (e.g. that an object in my code was obtained via `select_related()`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the particular case of a ForeignKey, you can check the existence of the `_FOO_cache` attribute. For instance, if your Employee object has a ForeignKey to Company, then if `my_employee.company` is populated then `my_employee._company_cache` will exist, so you can do `hasattr(my_employee, '_company_cache')`.

Comment: Is this public behavior that's documented somewhere? I can't seem to find it if that's the case, and I feel uneasy relying on an implementation detail that might change without notice in a future version of Django.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [TestCase.assertNumQueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/overview/#django.test.TestCase.assertNumQueries).

To check that `obj.accessor` doesn't hit the database:

```
# context manager version
with self.assertNumQueries(0):
  obj.accessor

# function version
self.assertNumQueries(0, lambda: obj.accessor)
```

Comment: This looks like a good answer, thanks. But I think I like @DanielRoseman's a little more because it can also be used in an `assert` statement in the code itself.